# express-validator throw errors on valid fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, express-validator

I'm using express-validator to validate user input in typescript api.
my validation chain:

```
  export const userValidator = [
  body("email").isEmpty().withMessage("email is required"),
  body("email").isEmail().withMessage("email is not valid"),

  body("username")
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage("first name has to be longer then 2 charecters"),
  body("username").isLength({ min: 2 }).withMessage("first name is required"),

  body("phoneNum").isNumeric().withMessage("enter a valid phone number"),

  body("password").isEmpty().withMessage("password is required"),
  body("password")
    .isLength({ min: 8 })
    .withMessage("password must be at least 8 characters"),

  body("confiremdPassword").custom((value: string, { req }) => {
    if (value !== req.body.password) {
      throw new Error("password have to match!");
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }),
];
```

and I am checking for errors in `auth.ts`:

```
 const errors = validationResult(req);
 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error: ServerError = new Error("Validation failed");
    error.status = 422;
    error.data = errors.array();
    throw error;
 }
```

but the result of this is very weird becuse I'm getting an array of all possible errors without a reason...

```
[
```

{
value: 'bro1@bro.com',
msg: 'email is required',
param: 'email',
location: 'body'
},
{
value: 'brrrrrro',
msg: 'first name has to be longer then 2 charecters',
param: 'username',
location: 'body'
},
{
value: undefined,
msg: 'enter a valid phone number',
param: 'phoneNum',
location: 'body'
},
{
value: 'brorrrrrrrr',
msg: 'password is required',
param: 'password',
location: 'body'
}
]
as you can see its even telling me email is empty even tho it tells me the value of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert your logic.

In your code you are telling express-validator that the email field MUST be empty, otherwise it will consider it as an error.

Just add `.not()` before the `.isEmpty()` validator.

`body("email").not().isEmpty().withMessage("email is required")`

If your field is required you could also add `.exists()`

Comment: you saved me  bro, thank yo so much